# webp file(Any unrecognized file) cannot be found in xcode bundle

Tags: swift, xcode, webp

It seems that webp file cannot be found and loaded through Bundle.main.url/path. But the gif file can be found. I use SDWebImage to load webp file from online url and it works:'
You can see from below pic that both methods return nil file and on the left panel you can see the file is there. Any idea is appreciated.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer. For the file type(extension) which can not be recognized by xcode, you have to manually add it from project->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources:
[image: settings]